# Check who/when updated a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have really hard time to answer this question to my colleagues, sometimes we have changes done on a table and we don't know who or when was changed, I have this query but it not really accurate sometimes.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'MYDB') --DB Name
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('MyTable') --Table Name
```

is there any other accurate way to answer this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### If you're talking about who altered the structure of a table

If it was recent enough, it may still be captured in the rolling [default trace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48053/1186):

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT 
  LoginName,
  HostName,
  StartTime,
  ObjectName,
  TextData
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass = 164    -- Object:Altered
AND EventSubClass = 1
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

If not, well, maybe it's time to invest in [DDL triggers](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), source control / change management, not giving all of your colleagues enough permissions to change the database, or all of the above...

### If you're talking about who changed data in a table

SQL Server doesn't track this data. You can look at a combination of DML triggers, SQL Audit, Change Tracking, Change Data Capture, [Temporal Tables](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4722/auditing-who-changed-temporal-table-data-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand). Your choice will depend on your version and edition of SQL Server, how much data is changing, and which tables you care about tracking...