# how to find an update on transaction log SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

This canned software that allows users to update all fields from an article and the only audit I got is who modified a particular record, but no audit record about what fields.

There is a policy that nobody should change some fields.

I'll implement something for this not happening in the future.

My concern now is how to find these updates in the transaction log. I know those files exits, no idea how to access them, query them, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check who/when updated a column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593379/check-who-when-updated-a-column-in-sql-server)

Comment: @ThomA that is useful to configure in the future, I'm trying to know what happened in the past. I'm installing Apex Log free trial in a test server at this moment hopping that helps

Comment: As the linked answer states; SQL Server doesn't store that by default, @German .

Comment: You can check out FN_DBLOG, it allows tracking updates to data, it's not easy to access, but there are some articles out there you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like the following:
https://www.sqlshack.com/reading-sql-server-transaction-log/

```
SELECT
  [Transaction ID], [Current LSN], [Transaction Name], [Operation],  [Context],[AllocUnitName],[Begin Time],[End Time], [Transaction SID],
  [Num Elements] ,
  [RowLog Contents 0],
  [RowLog Contents 1],
  [RowLog Contents 2],
  [RowLog Contents 3]
 FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
 WHERE [Transaction ID] = (Select [Transaction ID] FROM fn_dblog (null,null) WHERE
[Transaction Name] = 'INSERT')
```

GO